# RaisedButton vs ElevatedButton, FlatButton vs TextButton and OutlineButton vs OutlinedButton

Tags: flutter

I'm seeing the warning using old buttons:

> 'RaisedButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

> 'FlatButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

> 'OutlineButton' is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

So, what's the difference between:

- `RaisedButton` and `ElevatedButton`
- `FlatButton` vs `TextButton`
- `OutlineButton` vs `OutlinedButton`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First are obsolete classes.

Quotes from the Flutter [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html#:%7E:text=elevation%20increases%20when%20the%20button,such%20as%20dialogs%20or%20cards.):

> FlatButton, RaisedButton, and OutlineButton have been replaced by TextButton, ElevatedButton, and OutlinedButton respectively.

> The original classes will be deprecated soon, please migrate code that uses them.

Comment: I wish they would produce some good documentation for these three new classes. All I can find are the class declarations. Now examples or widget description documents.

Answer (score 34):

Here I found the docs for **[Migrating to the New Material Buttons and their Themes](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yohSuYrvyya5V1hB6j9pJskavCdVq9sVeTqSoEPsWH0/edit)**

The following image says itself what are the difference between all.

[image]

> Visually, the new buttons look a little different, because they match
> the current Material Design spec and because their colors are
> configured in terms of the overall Theme’s ColorScheme. There are
> other small differences in padding, rounded corner radii, and the
> hover/focus/pressed feedback.

You can check **[Changes Overview](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yohSuYrvyya5V1hB6j9pJskavCdVq9sVeTqSoEPsWH0/edit#heading=h.s6balucy11bi)** for more about changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer besides seeing black vs purple color in their text I didn't see any significant difference between the two except disabled `RaisedButton.icon` vs `ElevatedButton.icon` and that too is just a color change.

Answer (score 6):

These are obsolete classes, so eventually your old code needs to go away. (and, this [document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yohSuYrvyya5V1hB6j9pJskavCdVq9sVeTqSoEPsWH0/edit) will help you do exactly that.) However, that can be a lot of work, so to get things moving, I created some code to migrate the FlatButton and RaisedButton to the new TextButton and ElevatedButton 'in place'.  They are analogous to each other, but they approach styling in different ways, which this code handled.

Here's a link to the the gist if you want to run it in dartpad.dev (I couldn't get it to link directly):
https://gist.github.com/wterrill/7942b4bf5d74a8b2ace952ebf213fe5d

Here's the code itself:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bool disableButton = true; // <-- Change this to see buttons disabled
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              FlatButton(
                  child: Text("FlatButton"),
                  onPressed: disableButton
                      ? null
                      : () {
                          print("FlatButton normal");
                        },
                  color: Colors.green,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(50),
                      ),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple, width: 3.0)),
                  disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                  disabledTextColor: Colors.pink),
              SizedBox(height: 25),
              FlatButtonX(
                  childx: Text("TextButton"),
                  onPressedx: disableButton
                      ? null
                      : () {
                          print("FlatButtonX (TextButton)");
                        },
                  colorx: Colors.green,
                  textColorx: Colors.black,
                  shapex: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(50),
                      ),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple, width: 3.0)),
                  disabledColorx: Colors.grey,
                  disabledTextColorx: Colors.pink),
              SizedBox(height: 100),
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text('RaisedButton'),
                color: Colors.green,
                textColor: Colors.black,
                onPressed: disableButton
                      ? null
                      : () {
                          print("RaisedButton normal");
                        },
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(50),
                      ),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple, width: 3.0)),
                disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                  disabledTextColor: Colors.pink,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 25),
              RaisedButtonX(
                childx: Text('ElevatedButton'),
                colorx: Colors.green,
                textColorx: Colors.black,
                onPressedx:disableButton
                      ? null
                      : () {
                          print("RaisedButtonX (ElevatedButton)");
                        },
                shapex: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                        Radius.circular(50),
                      ),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.purple, width: 3.0)),
                                  disabledColorx: Colors.grey,
                  disabledTextColorx: Colors.pink,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget FlatButtonX(
    {Color colorx,
    @required Widget childx,
    RoundedRectangleBorder shapex,
    @required Function onPressedx,
    Key keyx,
    Color disabledColorx,
    Color disabledTextColorx,
    Color textColorx}) {
  if (disabledTextColorx == null && textColorx == null) {
    disabledTextColorx = colorx;
  }
  if (textColorx == null) {
    textColorx = colorx;
  }
  return TextButton(
      key: keyx,
      style: ButtonStyle(
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          // text color
          (Set<MaterialState> states) => states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)
              ? disabledTextColorx
              : textColorx,
        ),
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          // background color    this is color:
          (Set<MaterialState> states) =>
              states.contains(MaterialState.disabled) ? disabledColorx : colorx,
        ),
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(shapex),
      ),
      onPressed: onPressedx as void Function(),
      child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0), child: childx));
}

Widget RaisedButtonX(
    {Color colorx,
    @required Widget childx,
    RoundedRectangleBorder shapex,
    @required Function onPressedx,
    Key keyx,
    Color disabledColorx,
    Color disabledTextColorx,
    Color textColorx}) {
  if (disabledTextColorx == null && textColorx == null) {
    disabledTextColorx = colorx;
  }
  if (textColorx == null) {
    textColorx = colorx;
  }
  return ElevatedButton(
      key: keyx,
      style: ButtonStyle(
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          // text color
          (Set<MaterialState> states) => states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)
              ? disabledTextColorx
              : textColorx,
        ),
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
          // background color    this is color:
          (Set<MaterialState> states) =>
              states.contains(MaterialState.disabled) ? disabledColorx : colorx,
        ),
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(shapex),
      ),
      onPressed: onPressedx as void Function(),
      child: childx);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the advantages of `ElevatedButton` over `RaisedButton` is that it will actually pick up your main theme color by default.

So you don't even need to add that custom background color. You would only need to bring your own styling in `ElevatedButton`, if you want to deviate from your main theme or style other aspects of the button.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by `main theme color` here? `RaisedButton` does that too.

Comment: `RaisedButton` needed to be given Style explicitly. While `ElevatedButton` takes the Color of `primary Swatch` (Theme).

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that they are really equivalent.  According to the [Flutter 1.22 announcement](https://medium.com/flutter/announcing-flutter-1-22-44f146009e5f), the main motivation was around styling.  Prior to Flutter 1.22, there was only ONE ButtonTheme for 3 types of buttons, whereas now each type of button has its own theme.

Answer (score 1):

The FlatButton, RaisedButton and OutlineButton widgets have been replaced by TextButton, ElevatedButton, and OutlinedButton respectively.

Link explaining changes:

https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/buttons

How to use the buttons:

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets/material

Comment: Hi, this was already mentioned in almost all the answers. For the links, you could have posted a comment instead of taking the trouble to write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can't set `borderSide` nor `shape` either on OutlinedButton even though you could on OutlineButton

Comment: I think this is more suitable as comments than an answer.

Comment: Second, I didn't check yet, but I am sure you can set borderSide on OutlinedBorder too using the style property.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative buttons such as `TextButton`, `ElevatedButton`, and `OutlinedButton` are not quite easy like before. We can still use those legacy buttons using the [legacy_buttons](https://pub.dev/packages/legacy_buttons/) package

https://pub.dev/packages/legacy_buttons/

Comment: You could have written this as a comment.