# Flutter FlatButton is deprecated - alternative solution with width and height

Tags: flutter, deprecated, flatbutton

After Flutter Upgrade "FlatButton" is deprecated and I have to use TextButton instead. I didn't find a solution for a new button-type with width and height.

This is my working FlatButton. How can I solve it with textButton or elevatedButton?

```
_buttonPreview(double _height, double _width) {
    return FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {  },
      height: _height,
      minWidth: _width,
      color: Colors.grey,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      child: Text(
        "some text",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RaisedButton vs ElevatedButton, FlatButton vs TextButton and OutlineButton vs OutlinedButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64179998/raisedbutton-vs-elevatedbutton-flatbutton-vs-textbutton-and-outlinebutton-vs-ou)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I followed the guide here: https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/buttons.

```
_buttonPreview(double _height, double _width) {
  final ButtonStyle flatButtonStyle = TextButton.styleFrom(
    minimumSize: Size(_width, _height),
    backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
  );
  return TextButton(
    style: flatButtonStyle,
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text(
      "some text",
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You could do something like this.

*FlatButton To TextButton Migration*

```
    final ButtonStyle flatButtonStyle = TextButton.styleFrom(
      primary: Colors.white,
      minimumSize: Size(88, 44),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2.0)),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    );

    return TextButton(
      style: flatButtonStyle,
      onPressed: () {
        print('Button pressed');
      },
      child: Text('FlatButton To TextButton Migration'),
    );
  }
```

*Sample Buttons*

[image]

Reference

[Migrating to the New Material Buttons and their Themes](https://flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide)

[New Buttons and Button Themes](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/buttons)

Answer (score 17):

`FlatButton` is deprecated, so the best option is `ElevatedButton`.

Here is the code:

```
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.teal,
    fixedSize: Size.fromWidth(100),
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  ),
  child: Text("Press Here"),
  onPressed: () {
    //Code Here
  },
)
```

Answer (score 3):

FlatButton also can replace with MaterialButton

```
  MaterialButton(
                 onPressed: () {  },
                 height: _height,
                 minWidth: _width,
                 color: Colors.grey,
                 padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                 child: Text(
                     "some text",
                     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                   ),
                 ),
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `TextButton` instead of `FlatButton` in newer versions of flutter. It looks the same. for more info please read this
[Document](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/buttons).

```
TextButton(
           onPressed: () {/*what happened when tapped...*/},
           child: /*you can pass the widget you want to show in button, Usually use : Icon & Text*/
          ),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

from flutter docs -

**Migration guide**

Use the following information to migrate your buttons to the new API.

**Restoring the original button visuals**
In many cases it’s possible to just switch from the old button class to the new one. That’s assuming that the small changes in size/shape and the likely bigger change in colors, aren’t a concern.

To preserve the original buttons’ appearance in these cases, one can define button styles that match the original as closely as you like. For example, the following style makes a TextButton look like a default FlatButton:

```
final ButtonStyle flatButtonStyle = TextButton.styleFrom(
  primary: Colors.black87,
  minimumSize: Size(88, 36),
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2.0)),
  ),
);

TextButton(
  style: flatButtonStyle,
  onPressed: () { },
  child: Text('Looks like a FlatButton'),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a style that you might use for the button like this:

```
final ButtonStyle flatButtonStyle = TextButton.styleFrom(
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
  //few more styles 
);
```

Then use the above style while replacing your flatButton

```
return TextButton(
  style: flatButtonStyle,
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text(
    "some text",
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Customizable flat button widget.

[image]

*xflat_button.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class XFlatButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final void Function()? onPressed;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  final IconData? iconData;
  final Color bgColor;
   final Color fgColor;

  const XFlatButton(
      {required this.text,
      this.onPressed,
      this.width = 200,
      this.height = 40,
      super.key,
      this.iconData,
      this.bgColor = Colors.blue,
      this.fgColor = Colors.white});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ButtonStyle flatButtonStyle = TextButton.styleFrom(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
      ),
      backgroundColor: bgColor,
      foregroundColor: fgColor
    );
    return SizedBox(
      width: width,
      height: height,
      child: TextButton(
          onPressed: onPressed,
          style: flatButtonStyle,
          //child: Text(text),
          child: iconData == null
              ? Text(text, style: TextStyle(color: fgColor),)
              : Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
                  Icon(iconData, color: fgColor,),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 10,
                  ),
                  Text(text, style: TextStyle(color: fgColor),),
                ])),
    );
  }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
XFlatButton(
            text: 'Восстановить тему по умолчанию',
            width: 350,
            iconData: Icons.restore,
            bgColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary, 
            fgColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
            onPressed: (){
              ref.read(themeProvider.notifier).setState(defaultTheme);
            },
          ),
```

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me, Use:

```
ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text('Simple FlatButton'),
)
```

Instead of:

```
FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text('Simple FlatButton'),
)
```

Comment: ElevatedButton is not a FlatButton as it has an elevation property!

Answer (score -1):

```
_buttonPreview(double _height, double _width) {
    return MaterialButton(
      onPressed: () {  },
      height: _height,
      minWidth: _width,
      color: Colors.grey,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
      child: Text(
        "some text",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).