# in my android studio every button working but when i use flatbutton its not working so what can i do now?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies, knapsack-problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ApydE.png)

please how can i use flat button now?

I am trying to solve this and expected that someone will help me here.

Comment: FlatButton is removed by flutter now you need to use TextButton.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66805535/flutter-flatbutton-is-deprecated-alternative-solution-with-width-and-height

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter FlatButton is deprecated - alternative solution with width and height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66805535/flutter-flatbutton-is-deprecated-alternative-solution-with-width-and-height)

Comment: Share you code where you use faltbutton

Comment: FlatButton is deprecated(was in previous version of flutter), so now you can use ElevatedButton or FilledButton for same functionality as FlatButton

Comment: ok thanks to all of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You just need to Replace FlatButton to RaisedButton**

Comment: sir but i wanna use flat button i need it .