# RaisedButton widget has linethrow

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

[image]

I work on flutter app with android studio and i face a problem that raised button widget has a throw line
and the effect of it do not work (colors.blue)

Comment: Because  `onPressed` is null, it is disable color, try `onPressed:{}`

Comment: thanks,coloring worked . But why Raised button still has line throw it?

Comment: I guess you are using Flutter 2. It is because 'RaisedButton' is deprecated and shouldn't used. Use ElevatedButton instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RaisedButton vs ElevatedButton, FlatButton vs TextButton and OutlineButton vs OutlinedButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64179998/raisedbutton-vs-elevatedbutton-flatbutton-vs-textbutton-and-outlinebutton-vs-ou)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case, you can try

```
ElevatedButton(
        child: Text("Answer1", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize:30)),
        style: ButtonStyle(
          backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.black),
        ),
        onPressed: () {})
```

Answer (score 1):

'`RaisedButton`' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use `ElevatedButton` instead

```
@Deprecated(
  'Use ElevatedButton instead. See the migration guide in flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide). '
  'This feature was deprecated after v1.25.0-8.1.pre.'
)
class RaisedButton extends MaterialButton {
```